# libgdx ios landscape not fullscreen

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

I have trouble with my app. On iPhone (tested on 5c, 5s, 6) i have two black stripes on both sides (on android all looks well).
How i can dispose of them?

[image: two black stripes on both sides]

This is my code for drawing

```
@Override
public void create () {

    mWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
    mHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
    mScale = Math.max(mWidth, mHeight) / 20f;

    backgroundTexture = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("backBlue.png"));

    ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;

    backgroundShader = new ShaderProgram(VERT, FRAG);
    if (!backgroundShader.isCompiled()) {
        System.err.println(backgroundShader.getLog());
        System.exit(0);
    }
    if (backgroundShader.getLog().length()!=0)
        System.out.println(backgroundShader.getLog());

    backgroundBatch = new SpriteBatch(5, backgroundShader);
}


@Override
public void render () {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    backgroundBatch.begin();
    backgroundBatch.draw(backgroundTexture, 0, 0, mWidth, mHeight);
    backgroundBatch.end();
    ...
}

@Override
public void resize (int width, int height) {
    mWidth = width;
    mHeight = height;
    mScale = Math.max(width, height) / 20f;

    backgroundShader.begin();
    backgroundShader.setUniformf("resolution", width, height);
    backgroundShader.end();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is probably happening because the `viewport` you are using, which is usually set in the constructor or the `create` method.

**What is a `viewport`?**

Basically, a `viewport` is an object that is created to define the policy of how the game will be drawn on different screens. E.g., say your camera is set to be 480 x 800 (pixels). What happens if your game is running on a screen that has a different ratio, for instance, the iPhone 5 that has a screen of 1,136 × 640 pixels? Should the game be stretched? Should the image be cropped? Or should `libgdx` add black bars on either side to fit the camera size you are using? This decision is made by the `viewport` your camera is using.

This is it in a nutshell. It is highly recommended to read more on this on the [wiki](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports).

Additionally, a good tutorial on this subject can be found [here](http://www.gamefromscratch.com/post/2014/12/09/LibGDX-Tutorial-Part-17-Viewports.aspx).